# Cannot Delete General Log File for MySQL - Shows Still Open In Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, logfile

I am attempting to delete the General Log File for MySQL, but I get the message

```
'The action can't be completed because the file is open in MySQL Workbench.'
```

I don't see the log file open, and I have turned it off via query in MySQL Workbench.  Is there another way to ensure that the log is not open in Workbench?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you tried already to close your Workbench instance to have it give up the file handle for the log? Also, a Workbench process might be hung due to some weird condition. Check with e.g. Process Explorer or Task Manager to see if there's a dead instance still running. Kill that and you should be able to remove the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks - When I ran Task Manager, there were no applications running, so I installed Process Explorer and that found the running instance of Workbench. I killed it, and now I have been able to delete the log file